# PHP: Preg_match and replace all

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have an obvious hyperlink which I all want to replace in a text to just normal HTML hyperlinks.
So this just works for one hyperlink:

```
$string = '<u>\\n\\\\*HYPERLINK \\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0VUsoeT9aM\\"A Youtube Video</u>';
$pattern = '/http[?.:=\\w\\d\\/]*/';
$namePattern = '/(?:")([\\s\\w]*)</';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
preg_match($namePattern, $string, $nameMatches);

echo '<a href="'.$matches[0].'">'.$nameMatches[1].'</a>';
```

But there are more hyperlinks than just one in a text so I want to just change all of these hyperlinks:

```
 <?php 
    $input = 'Blablabla Beginning Text <u>\\n\\\\*HYPERLINK \\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0VUsoeT9aM\\"1.A Youtube Video</u> blablabla Text Middle <u>\\n\\\\*HYPERLINK \\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0VUsoeT9aM\\"2. A Youtube Video</u> blabla Text after';
    //To become:
    $output = 'Blablabla Beginning Text <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0VUsoeT9aM">1. A Youtube Video</a>blablabla Text Middle <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0VUsoeT9aM">2. A Youtube Video</a> blabla Text after';
    ?>
```

How would I do that?

Comment: So use [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all) instead?

Comment: Yea but how to display all these hyperlinks with surrounding text?

Comment: @MegaCookie overwrite the $string again .

Comment: You don't need to double escape character classes like `\d` or `\w`.

Comment: @Ancient Geek You mean just foreach found hyperlink replace the next hyperlink? I don't know if this is performance effective but I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to replace the found matches, then use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) which does exactly that. However, you'll run into one obvious problem: Currently there are two instances of `preg_match()` - should those be replaced by two instances of `preg_replace()`? No. Combine them.

```
$pattern = '/http[?.:=\w\d\\/]*/';
$namePattern = '/(?:")([\s\w]*)</';
```

Can be combined to *(I added `.` to the `$namePattern` part, so it can work with the second example text where the link description contains a dot)*:

```
$replacePattern = '/(http[?.:=\w\d\\/]*)\\\\"([\s\w.]*)</';
```

Because link and text are separated by `\\"` in the original text. I tested via `preg_match_all()` if this pattern works and it does. Also by adding `()` to the first pattern, they are now grouped.

```
$replacePattern = '/(http[?.:=\w\d\\/]*)\\\\"([\s\w.]*)</';
//                  ^-group1-----------^     ^-group2-^
```

These groupes can now be used in the replace statement.

```
$replaceWith = '<a href="\\1">\\2</a><';
```

Where `\\1` points to the first group and `\\2` to the second. The `<` at the end is necessary because `preg_replace()` will replace the whole found pattern (not just groups) and since the `<` is at the end of the pattern, we would lose it if it wasn't in the replace part.

All that you now need, is to call `preg_replace()` with this parameters like the following:

```
$output = preg_replace($replacePattern, $replaceWith, $string);
```

All occurences of the `$replacePattern` will now be replaced with their version of `$replaceWith` and saved in the variable `$output`.

---

You can see it [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6d4pS4).

---

If you want a larger part to be removed, just extend the `$replacePattern`.

```
$replacePattern = '/<u>.*?(http[?.:=\w\d\\/]*)\\\\"([\s\w.]+)<\/u>/';
$replaceWith = '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>';
```

(see it [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EvE0xa)) `.*?` will match everything and is *not greedy*, meaning it will stop once it finds the first occurence of whatever comes after (so here it is `http...`).

Comment: Thanks this just works fine for replacing the links, but I want to remove the <u> \n\\*HYPERLINK \"</u> part too. What would you recommend to do? And I'm running into a strange situation, if the Url name has an dot in it, it only creates an hyperlink between till that dot.